# Call Function within User-Defined Function in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I want to include the following function inside of another user-defined function in Oracle.

`DBMS_STATS.GATHER_TABLE_STATS(SCHEMA_IN,TABLE_IN)`

`SCHEMA_IN` and `TABLE_IN` are arguments to the user-defined function.  However, I get the following error.

`ORA-14552: cannot perform a DDL, commit or rollback inside a query or DML`

How can I resolve this?  Below is my SQL script.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE Function GET_COLUMNS (SCHEMA_IN IN VARCHAR2, NAME_IN IN VARCHAR2)
RETURN VARCHAR2
is
L_TEXT VARCHAR2(32767) := NULL;
BEGIN
DBMS_STATS.GATHER_TABLE_STATS(SCHEMA_IN,NAME_IN);
FOR CUR_REC IN (SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM USER_TAB_COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = name_in AND NUM_NULLS = 0) LOOP
   L_TEXT := L_TEXT || ',' || CUR_REC.COLUMN_NAME;
END LOOP;
return(ltrim(l_text,','));
END;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gather_table_stats` is a procedure, not a function.  And it a procedure that includes transaction control logic (presumably, a commit at least).  You cannot, therefore, call it in a function that is called from SQL.  You could call your function from PL/SQL rather than SQL,

```
DECLARE
  l_text varchar2(4000);
BEGIN
  l_text := get_columns( <<schema>>, <<table>> );
END;
```

I would, however, be very, very dubious about the approach you're taking.

First, `dbms_stats` gathers statistics that are used by the optimizer.  Using those statistics in other contexts is generally dangerous.  Most `dbms_stats` calls involve some level of indeterminism-- you're generally gathering data from a sample of rows and extrapolating.  That is perfectly appropriate for giving the optimizer information so that it can judge things like roughly how many rows a table scan will return.  It may not be appropriate if you're trying to differentiate between a column that is never `NULL` and one that is very rarely `NULL`.  Some samples may catch a `NULL` value, others may not.  It may seem to work correctly for months or years and then start to fail either consistently or intermittantly.

Second, when you gather fresh statistics, you're potentially forcing Oracle to do hard parses on all the existing SQL statements that reference the table.  That can be a major performance hit if you do this in the middle of the day.  If you happen to force a query plan to change in a bad way, you'll likely cause the DBA a great deal of grief.  If the DBA is gathering statistics in a particular way (locking statistics on some tables, forcing histograms on others, forcing a lack of histograms on others, etc.) to deal with performance issues, it's highly likely that you'll be either working at cross purposes or actively breaking the other.

Third, if a column never has `NULL` values, it really ought to be marked as `NOT NULL`.  Then you can simply look at the data dictionary to see which columns are nullable and which are not without bothering to gather statistics.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @justin-cave!  Basically, I need a function/procedure that will return all of the non-null columns for a particular row in a data table.  I have a website that takes information from a survey and populates a data table in the database.  I then want to go in and see what columns were populated by a particular user.  Do you have any suggestions of how this could be done more consistently?

Comment: @user13317 - What does "data table" mean in this context?  That's normally something that you associate with a front-end display, not a physical heap-organized table in a database.  If you want to see which columns were populated by a particular user, I would assume that you'd be looking at a subset of rows in a database table and performing some logic on those rows.  You'd need to edit your question (or post a new question) with the data model, some sample data, and the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your function to be an autonomous transaction to execute gather table stats:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE Function GET_COLUMNS (SCHEMA_IN IN VARCHAR2, NAME_IN IN VARCHAR2)
   RETURN VARCHAR2
as
   pragma autonomous_transaction;
   L_TEXT VARCHAR2(32767) := NULL;
BEGIN
```